# How to request permission for Linkedin basic_profile?

Tags: linkedin

We have developed a signup via LinkedIn app. We currently get the default “lite profile” but need access to the “basic profile” We’ve tried reaching out to all parts of LinkedIn but to no avail. The links to the Partner Program Page also seem deprecated. Can someone please share how we can get the upgraded permissions pls?